# StateObject without @Published properties

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a question about the logic of the `@StateObject`. Let's say we have a class initialised inside the view which has 0 `@Published` properties, but we don't want it to be reinitialised by the `View`. Should it be made a `@StateObject` to prevent that or is it bad practice to conform to `ObservableObject` without having observable data. Example:

```
class Downloader {
    private var isDownloading = false

    func download(for id: String) {
        isDownloading = true
        // download
        isDownloading = false
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
    var downloader: Downloader()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear {
                downloader.download(for: "id")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a concrete example *with* code. It is unclear what situation you are talking about.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the post with a dummy example.

Comment: Okay, why would your view have such a thing as one of its properties in the first place if it doesn't need to observe `isDownloading`? How about just creating the downloader on-the-fly, e.g. `Downloader().download(for: "id")` in `onAppear`?

Comment: You could use State but it can sometimes leak. SwiftUI property wrappers are meant to track changes for SwiftUI views you likely need more of an architectured setup for this.

Comment: You should vision a SwiftUI view as a _function_ where the fields of the struct are function parameters. This function either _creates_ an underlying view or _mutates_ the underlying view, which is responsible to render things. Now, you will see, that whenever you make changes to the declarative view, it will create a new `Downloader` object - something you definitely don't want to happen. However, when you use a `@StateObject` - this will _not_ happen - it will be created only once, when the underlying view is created. The better way to solve your problem, is not to use this object at all ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper problem is the framework is not strict on how the functionality it provides should be used. Using a StateObject will ensure the object will be created only once - but nothing is stopping us from NOT using any Published properties inside of it - which afaik is the whole purpose of ObservableObject. i.e. it makes sense for ObservableObject wrapped with StateObject to not be recreated when it is supposed to keep state of Published properties, but nothing is stopping us from not using any such properties and only use the declaration to achieve 'single instance creation'

Comment: @Petar I think, you can use a class conforming to protocol `ObservableObject` _without_  actually publishing a value and without weird consequences. IMHO, the object would just not publish anything and not causing the view to update. But, I think you can achieve the same using `@State`, where the wrapped value is an object reference which you can initialise (once). Do you think, that fits better?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper In my experiment State wrapped property does get initialized every time the view redraws. What am I missing - if you can please https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256963/swiftui-stateobject

Answer (score 0):

your aim should be avoid class whenever you can, shared mutable state leads to bugs which is why SwiftUI uses `View` struct for view data, `.task` makes it possible to do async work with no need for a class but still have the lifetime tied to something on screen, e.g.

```
struct Downloader {
   
    func download(for id: String) async throws -> [Items] {
        
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
   
    let downloadID: String
    @State var isDownloading = false
    @State var result: [Items]?
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .task(id: downloadID){
                isDownloading = true
                let downloader: Downloader() // usually this is in the @Environment
                result = try? await downloader.download(for: downloadID)
                isDownloading = false
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Downloader` is only for `SwiftUI.View`s you can put it into the `Environment`.

```
actor DownloaderProvider {
    func download(for id: String) async throws -> [String] {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        return [UUID().uuidString, UUID().uuidString]
    }
}

private struct DownloaderProviderKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: DownloaderProvider = .init() //Init once
}


extension EnvironmentValues {
    var downloaderProvider: DownloaderProvider {
        get { self[DownloaderProviderKey.self] }
        set { self[DownloaderProviderKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then you can access it in any `SwiftUI.View`

```
struct DummyView: View {
    @Environment(\.downloaderProvider) var downloaderProvider
    @State private var downloadID: String? = "id"
    @State var result: [String] = []
    var body: some View {
        Text("isDownloading == \((downloadID != nil).description)")
        Text("Hello")
            .task(id: downloadID){ //Triggers a download when the id changes.
                guard let downloadID else {return}
                do {
                    result = try await downloaderProvider.download(for: downloadID)
                } catch {
                    print(error) // << present error to user
                }
                self.downloadID = nil
            }
    }
}
```

If you need to access the same instance of `Downloader` from non-Views you have to implement something similar to `EnvironmentValues`.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

I also suggest looking at the pros/cons of `actor` when dealing with something like a "Downloader" and actor can be beneficial.

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swift-actors/